# Example with marginal independences, but not conditional independence

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

Let $A,B,C$ be random variables and suppose $A \perp\!\!\!\perp B$ and $A \perp\!\!\!\perp  C$, but that $B$ and $C$ are not independent. Is it true that $A \perp\!\!\!\perp  B | C$? I suspect that the answer is no, but I'm struggling to find an example that verifies this.

Any help/hints will is appreciated.

Comment: There is standard example of pair-wise indepdent events $A,B,C$ which are not together independent.

Comment: I agree - thank you! However, I was really after the case when $B$ and $C$ are not independent. I will edit the question right away; sorry for not specifying the question precisely!